# Deploying existing Elastic Beanstalk inside VPC without deleting the RDS associated

Tags: amazon-web-services, static, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vpc

I've currently in production a beanstalk with loadbalanced instances, and an associated RDS. Also got some routing/dns configuration that allow me to call my beanstalk with a "straight" domain name.

I'm in the need to assign a static IP my Elastic Beanstalk Application so I can give it to a 3rd party that will need to whitelist me so I can call it.

I saw, regarding [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390610/static-ip-using-elastic-beanstalk), that this can be achieved with VPC

I followed the procedure except for the RDS part.

Now I think that I need to delete my environnement (so the DB too) and launch it again within the VPC ? But is there a way to do that without deleting my  -prod- database ?

Also, will this procedure change any behavior for my existing setup ? And will it work fine ? I mean as far as I can imagine, here is a theorical situation:

-Some user enters my portal from this url http://awsomeDomain.com (which ends to my beanstalk instances). He try to 'identify himself' so I make him enter his cellphone number. Now I got it and I want to call my third party with this number to it tells me what is the state of this phone number.

Will I be able to, inside my php code (from my beanstalk) make this call From the elastic IP assigned to my VPC ? It is a bit confusing to me as far as I feel like using this VPC is more of a trick than a real solution and that I don't use it on it's main purpose.

So right here I got my VPC, basically configured (from the tutorial) and I'm not sure what to do.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact for everyone that already has or have the problem. It is quite easy.

Create new fresh EC instances (2, maybe 3 to handle traffic). Assign Elastic IPs to that instances. Make a loadbalancer handling the traffic. And then you have a Gateway to work like this :

1) From my application client clicks

2) My application calls my EC2 static instances with all params

3) My Static EC2 calls my third party

4) third party answer to my EC2

5) EC2 answers to my application

Answer (score 2):

The best way to delete your Beanstalk application without loosing your data is to create a snapshot and then create the new app with the snapshot to seed the db.

For the rest, it is a separate question and I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: For this "seperate" question , my point is to know if I do deletion of the beanstalk and I do the procedure we're talking of, will it be possible for me to keep my app like it is + sending request from the static IP to the 3rd party ?

Comment: I do not fully understand your problem but what I would do is to configure without beanstalk the VPC, the entry point (the server with the static IP), the subnets and the RDS. And then use beanstalk for your application, passing your RDS configuration via env vars. This is a typical deployment. You have to mix several examples you can find in the AWS doc. Using a EC2 router outside beanstalk is describe there for instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo-vpc-no-nat.html

Comment: Thanks, this procedure looks tricky starting from an Elastic Beanstalk doing all the job by itself within a production environement, I will meditate on that. My problem in an easiest way: will I be able to receive call from the classic beanstalk url, then identify the user that did the call and then call a 3rd party but from the Elastic IP ? I want to be sure that the 3rd party I call get called by the static IP

Comment: This is mainly a software task. In term of infrastructure, as long as the routing and security rules are correctly configured, this can be done with problem.