# How can I use single pre-resgistered ip for outbounding request to specific host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I need to use external 3-rd party API, and it's vendor requires us to register IP address for the request source.

But with elastic beanstalk along with application load balancer and auto scaling group,
all public IPs assigned to each ec2 instances are auto-generated in random manner.

Cases are below,

1. every instances inside load balancer can request to 3-rd party vendor server for data.
2. Vendor only send response to pre-registered IP address. If request source address is not in list, it reject to send response.

The instances reside in default VPC.

How can I use single IP for outbounding request?

Comment: Create a different subnet with a NAT gateway in it and a route to the IGW, create an EIP and assign it to the nat, set up routing so that either all or at least the traffic to the api goes through that nat gateway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Public IP address for outgoing traffic AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757889/public-ip-address-for-outgoing-traffic-aws)

Comment: @luk2302, Im using default VPC with 4 default subnets in which inside each AZ, is it possible to create single NAT and forward all 4 subnet to use NAT? -- It seems possible though problematic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59525729/2442804 - apparently that is possible, yes.