# Amazon NAT gateway not working - Instances not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run an Elastic Beanstalk setup, with a dynamic amount of servers, with dynamic IP's, an external provider needs to whitelist our IP, so I need to route all my traffic out via a NAT gateway.

I am using the default public VPC, with 3 default subnets.
I have created a new Subnet, and a new NAT gateway, which I have placed on this new subnet.

I have created a new route table for this new subnet, where 0.0.0.0/0 points to an internet gateway.

I have changed the routes from the other 3 default subnets from 0.0.0.0/0 (Internet Gateway) to 0.0.0.0/0 (NAT Gateway).

My instances become inaccessible after i do this, what seems to be the issue, and where can i find some logs?

Comment: Not clear why your instances are inaccessible if you change the route. Are you saying your instances cannot reach the internet?

Comment: @helloV it sounds like the instances have public IP addresses and the public subnets they are on... are being flipped to become private subnets... which isn't going to be a valid configuration.

Comment: Yes, the instances have public IP addresses, what can i do to fix it?

Comment: You want to access/ssh your instances in public subnet. Is that your only issue? I am confused by the title `NAT gateway not working`

Comment: I am confused. You should be using CIDR addresses that you assigned during the NAT Gateway setup to get to your subnets not 0.0.0.0

Comment: The issue is that i cannot access my instances via the internet, it timeouts, when i set up the NAT gateway.

Comment: Please check the solution stated here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390610/static-ip-using-elastic-beanstalk

Comment: @IvanRistic I am having the same issue right now. Where you ever able to solve this? We have likey followed the same guides as my steps are identical to yours.